# ANOVA in R - Grouping

Tags: r, statistical-significance, anova

I'm trying to do an ANOVA-analysis in R where I'm trying to find out if repeated measurements of a certain quantity are consistent if the measurement is being repeated 10 times. And I'm also trying to find out if the measurements are consistent if a different person is carrying out the measurement. So I've got a dataframe like this (`dput()`at the bottom of the question):

```
> anova.df
   measurement.number not.relevant person measured.quant.1 measured.quant.2 measured.quant.3
1                   1            x      A           -8.616           -8.627           -8.600
2                   1            x      B           -8.616           -8.628           -8.595
3                   2            x      A           -8.612           -8.628           -8.599
4                   2            x      B           -8.620           -8.631           -8.597
5                   3            x      A           -8.603           -8.624           -8.597
6                   3            x      B           -8.619           -8.635           -8.603
7                   4            x      A           -8.609           -8.625           -8.600
8                   4            x      B           -8.618           -8.646           -8.603
9                   5            x      A           -8.610           -8.617           -8.600
10                  5            x      B           -8.617           -8.636           -8.589
11                  6            x      A           -8.606           -8.625           -8.593
12                  6            x      B           -8.608           -8.627           -8.596
13                  7            x      A           -8.612           -8.631           -8.603
14                  7            x      B           -8.615           -8.617           -8.601
15                  8            x      A           -8.594           -8.611           -8.584
16                  8            x      B           -8.617           -8.630           -8.601
17                  9            x      A           -8.601           -8.630           -8.600
18                  9            x      B           -8.618           -8.626           -8.601
19                 10            x      A           -8.608           -8.626           -8.598
20                 10            x      B           -8.617           -8.624           -8.595
```

So lets say I'm doing the analysis for the first quantity:

```
anova.ws <- aov(data = anova.df, measured.quant.1 ~ measurement.number + person)
summary(anova.ws)

                   Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
measurement.number  9 0.0002262 0.0000251   0.946 0.53249   
person              1 0.0004418 0.0004418  16.623 0.00277 **
Residuals           9 0.0002392 0.0000266                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

That would mean it does matter if person A or B is conducting the measurement, but the single measurements the person is conducting are basically the same, right?

ANOVA is basically comparing the means of the groups, right? If I'm grouping by `measurement.number` and `person` does that mean I'm comparing single values with each other? Because

```
> anova.df %>% group_by(measurement.number, person)
# A tibble: 20 x 6
# Groups:   measurement.number, person [20]
```

returns 20 groups, which is the size of the data frame.

I'm not very good at statistics so now I'm wondering if i did the analysis correctly and if my conclusion is correct. I'm grateful for any input!

EDIT: For clarification, what I'm trying to find out is if there's a difference between the persons doing the measurement and if there's a difference between the measurements each person is conducting. Ideally the answer to both questions would be no.

Data:

```
structure(list(measurement.number = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
"10"), class = "factor"), not.relevant = c("x", "x", "x", "x", 
"x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", 
"x", "x", "x"), person = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), measured.quant.1 = c(-8.616, -8.616, 
-8.612, -8.62, -8.603, -8.619, -8.609, -8.618, -8.61, -8.617, 
-8.606, -8.608, -8.612, -8.615, -8.594, -8.617, -8.601, -8.618, 
-8.608, -8.617), measured.quant.2 = c(-8.627, -8.628, -8.628, 
-8.631, -8.624, -8.635, -8.625, -8.646, -8.617, -8.636, -8.625, 
-8.627, -8.631, -8.617, -8.611, -8.63, -8.63, -8.626, -8.626, 
-8.624), measured.quant.3 = c(-8.6, -8.595, -8.599, -8.597, -8.597, 
-8.603, -8.6, -8.603, -8.6, -8.589, -8.593, -8.596, -8.603, -8.601, 
-8.584, -8.601, -8.6, -8.601, -8.598, -8.595)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collusion is correct that the measurement is insignificant but the person is a significant variable.  A simple way to visualize this is to plot the boxplot of the measurement with the measurement number and then with the person.

```
anova.ws <- aov(data = anova.df, measured.quant.1 ~ measurement.number + person)
summary(anova.ws)
boxplot(data = anova.df, measured.quant.1 ~ measurement.number, xlab="Measured.quant1")
boxplot(data = anova.df, measured.quant.1 ~ person, xlab="person")
```

[image]
[image]

From the boxplots the variation from measurement ID to measurement ID is similar, but the difference from person A to person B is significant.

Since it looks like each measurement ID was repeated 3 times, you can gather the repeats and perform the ANOVA again. The repeated measurements is more variable than the person to person variability.

```
library(tidyr)
df<-gather(anova.df, key=mrepeat, value=value, -c(1:3))
anova.ws <-aov(data = df, value ~ measurement.number + person + mrepeat)
summary(anova.ws)
boxplot(data = df, value ~ person + measurement.number)
```